# Function call changing its argument python

Tags: python-3.x, function, function-calls

I am trying to reduce a matrix to its echlon form using a function but upon the calling the function, it is also changing its arguments. Here is the code

```
def GaussE(E,r):
    N = np.size(r)
    for i in range(0,N-1):
        for j in range(i+1,N):
            f=(E[j,i]/E[i,i])
            r[j]= r[j] -(f)*r[i]             
            for k in range(i,N):                          
                E[j,k] = E[j,k]-(f*E[i,k])  
    return(E,r)
A = np.array([[5.10,8.70],[2.40,4.10]])
b = np.array([9.48,4.48])
print(A,b)
```

> output: [[ 5.1  8.7] [ 2.4  4.1]] [ 9.48  4.48]

```
X = GaussE(A[:],b[:])
print(A,b) # Why is A and b changing? they should not change
```

> output:[[  5.10000000e+00   8.70000000e+00]
>    [  0.00000000e+00   5.88235294e-03]] [ 9.48        0.01882353]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python every variable refers to an object. It refers to the object pointer so it is using the object itself.
In that function you are referencing `E` like `E[j,k]` and `r` like `r[j]` and assigning to it which means you are using **that same object** and means you are manipulating it.
Try to use `copy` at the first of your function (`from copy import copy`)

```
from copy import copy

def GaussE(E,r):
    E = copy(E)
    r = copy(r)
    N = np.size(r)
    for i in range(0,N-1):
        for j in range(i+1,N):
            f=(E[j,i]/E[i,i])
            r[j]= r[j] -(f)*r[i]             
            for k in range(i,N):                          
                E[j,k] = E[j,k]-(f*E[i,k])  
    return(E,r)
A = np.array([[5.10,8.70],[2.40,4.10]])
b = np.array([9.48,4.48])
print(A,b)
```